# Access private docker registry in browser

Tags: browser, docker, docker-registry

I have a `private docker registry` like `myregistry.com:5000`. I can push and pull images in client and it is working fine. But when I go to `https://myregistry.com:5000/v1` in browser, I get error `404 page not found`. Is there any way to access registry in browser?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The url should be https://myregistry.com:5000/v2.

But regarding UI, you have several projects dedicated to browse a docker registry, like:

- [kwk/docker-registry-frontend](https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend),
- [Portus (suse)](https://github.com/SUSE/Portus)
- other referentials (like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2015/11/02/premium-docker-registry/) or GitLab)

Comment: Thanks for your response but isn't there any way to access url https://myregistry.com:5000/v2 without using `kwk/docker-registry-frontend`?

Comment: @saurg no, as mentioned in Elton's answer. You need to install a tool to browse that registry.

Comment: how to use this frontend with SSL encryption enabled if I have my files at `/certs/domain.crt` and `/certs/domain.key` in reference with `kwk/docker-registry-frontend` ?

Comment: @saurg That I am not sure: ask a new question, and close (ie select an accepted answer) for this one.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've put a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087966/private-docker-registry-frontend-with-ssl-encryption. If you can ask anyone to answer, that would be great.

Comment: @saurg By asking a new questions, you jsut "asked everyone" to answer! In the meantime, don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I am facing an issue in kwk frontend that v2 sometimes when I click on "Browse Repositories" on the main page it goes to "http://localhost/repositories/20" (searches for 20; which shows nothing obviously).

Comment: @saurg OK. Again asking a new question is best here.

Answer (score 9):

The `registry:2` image doesn't have a Web UI - it's not a local version of Docker Hub, it just has the core registry functionality and the [REST API](https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/registry/spec/api/).

You can query the API directly:

```
> curl http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":[]}
```

If you want a Web UI like the Hub, try [Docker Trusted Registry](https://docs.docker.com/docker-trusted-registry/).

Comment: For people interested in DTR, note that installing it requires docker UCP (https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/dtr/2.4/guides/admin/install/#step-2-install-ucp), which requires docker EE (enterprise edition) (https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/2.2/guides/admin/install/#step-2-install-docker-ee-on-all-nodes).

Answer (score 0):

Pull the docker registry using:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 registry:2
```

You can view the registries using the URL.

```
http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
```

[image]