# Private Docker registry frontend with SSL encryption

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, frontend, docker-registry

I am using https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend for my private docker registry frontend. How to use this frontend with SSL encryption enabled if I have my files at `/certs/domain.crt` and `/certs/domain.key`? 
There is one section https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend#ssl-encryption which talks about it but I'm not sure about following steps

`-v $PWD/server.crt:/etc/apache2/server.crt:ro \`

`-v $PWD/server.key:/etc/apache2/server.key:ro \`

I'm not using apache. I simply have my crt and key at location mentioned above. How to use it these two at above two steps?
It would be good if I understand the meaning of these two steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deal is the kwk-frontend has its own apache to serve application, so this step is aimed to mount yours ssl certificates from host machine to inside of frontend container, so internal apache can serve it with ssl enabled.
In your particular case it will be:

```
-v /certs/domain.crt:/etc/apache2/server.crt:ro \
-v /certs/domain.key:/etc/apache2/server.key:ro \
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `docker-registry-frontend` keeps on exiting itself immediately as I run it with SSL encryption command enabled. What could be the issue?

Comment: @saurg, I had no such problem before, so I cannot guess what a reason is =) but I definetly can say that you need to check `docker logs -f --tail=100 name_of_container` for errors or warnings.  

Frankly speaking, I am currently using [my own frontend](https://github.com/Evedel/bow), because I couldn't find lot of features that I need in others. Sorry, if it looks like an adv =)

Comment: that's awesome :) but I need a basic UI so using this kwk frontend only. Is is possible that sometimes, it takes a little longer to load and doesn't show any repository even if repository is there?

Comment: kwk frontend is stateless, that in other words, it makes registry api call for any your activity and don't save those data, so, yes, it can take some time.

Comment: But the time it takes to load completely doesn't mean that is not working fine in any way..right?

Comment: It is just that I have `hello-world` image in my registry but the frontend doesn't show any repository and repository page keeps on loading. kind of worried what could be the reason as sometimes it behaves like this.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to check the both logs of frontend and logs  registry (with same `docker logs`) to see what exactly happen on both services when you trying to obtain some data.

Comment: The problem is sometimes when I click on "Browse Repositories" on the main page it goes to "http://localhost/repositories/20" (searches for 20; which shows nothing obviously).